# How can an inner product be defined through a proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I'm having a really hard time with question b of the image below, (Find any non-trivial A and B such that they are orthogonal) and question c, the proof.

I know that non trivial means a nonzero solution, but how do I interpret the subscript? And does part c utilize Cauchy Schwarz? It looks almost like the pythagorean theorem but I'm not sure if I'm way off.

Any help or guidance you can provide would be super helpful, thanks! [image: problem here]

Comment: "Below"?  Did you mean to attach something?

Comment: @JacobManaker yes, I thought it was showing up but maybe not -- I just updated it with a link at the bottom if it's not working! Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: For part (b): can you think of numbers such that $a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} = 0$, but not all of the $a$'s are zero, and similarly for the $b$'s? hint: $1/2 + 1/2 + (-1) = 0$. For part (c): Have you heard of the "Cauchy-Schwarz inequality," perhaps during multivariable calculus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b) we need only find $A$ and $B$ non-zero so that the inner product is $0$, i.e.,
$$ \langle A, B \rangle = \left\langle \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12}\\ 0 & a_{22} \end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} b_{11} & b_{12}\\ 0 & b_{22} \end{bmatrix}\right\rangle 
= a_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}b_{12} + a_{22}b_{22} = 0$$
So one easy example would be taking $a_{11}=a_{12}=b_{22}=0$. This would give a sum of zeros, even if $A$ or $B$ were non-trivial. For instance,

$$ A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad
B= \begin{bmatrix} 3 & -17\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix},\qquad \text{then $\langle A,B\rangle = 0$}$$

As for c), you are correct in recognizing the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. As we have an inner product, it must satisfy
$$\langle A, B\rangle^2 \leq \langle A, A\rangle \langle B,B\rangle$$
where
$$\langle A, B\rangle^2 = (a_{11}b_{11}+a_{12}b_{12}+a_{22}b_{22})^2$$
$$\langle A, A\rangle \langle B,B\rangle
= (a_{11}a_{11}+a_{12}a_{12}+a_{22}a_{22})(b_{11}b_{11}+b_{12}b_{12}+b_{22}b_{22})
= (a_{11}^2+a_{12}^2+a_{22}^2)(b_{11}^2+b_{12}^2+b_{22}^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can map each of this matrix to a vector of size 3. In each matrix there is a a zero entry. Ignore that zero and take the other three entries as components of a vector )that is the x,y,z co-ordinates)..

After this process it is clear that this question is not really about matrices, it is the same question as for $\mathbf{R}^3$.

If you have written computer programs the above process can be viewed this way. In a program we use, 2d-arrays, or 3d-arrays etc. A 2d-array can be scanned row by row and mapped to a 1-d array (that is what we have done).

Comment: Downvote because the relevance of your statements to the problem is unclear.

Comment: My answer was under the assumption the OP knows about inner products in $R^3$.  Then my suggestion would make him see that matrices are irrelevant here.